# open an image in a function with python

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

can anyone tell me if there is a way to open an image inside a function, without installing PIL or pillow or Xcode?

example: (not real code)

def some_function():

```
  open image("some image")
```

return

If the only way is to use PIL or Pillow, how do I use it for Jupiter notebook?

(Installing PIL, Pillow and Xcode is quite confusing, I'm using Python 3 on macOS)

Thanks

Comment: what do you intend to after opening the image? what do you actually mean by the term "opening"? read or convert?

Comment: I would like the image to appear once it reaches a point in the function. I just want to be able to see the image

Comment: Why can't you use PIL or Pillow?

Comment: I'm new to this part of programming and am just trying to find out if there are other ways, or if PIL or Pillow is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

You could read images with OpenCV `imread` function.

```py
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it is easy to install Pillow if you have pip (Python Package Index). Just go to Terminal and type: `pip install Pillow`

Second, if you are using Anaconda, Pillow works on Spyder. If not, you'd have to find something else to use. I recommend Anaconda.

Comment: ok great, I will try both ways. Could you also tell me, after I install Pillow, what do I type inside the function to access the image? Does the image need to be in a specific folder? Thanks in advance